# South Korea 30-day visa exemption

Tags: visas, south-korea, us-residents

I’m planning on visiting Seoul for a few days. I'm not a US citizen but I'm a permanent resident. I’ve read online about South Korea’s 30-day visa exemption:

> Non-visa-exempt nationals who are in transit through South Korea are visa-exempt for 30 days, provided holding a physical visa or a residence permit issued by the following countries and are arriving at South Korea from one of these countries and continuing to a third country, or arriving from a third country and continuing to one of these countries
>
> Australia1
>
> Canada
>
> New Zealand
>
> United States

My itinerary is USA>Philippines>Taiwan>Seoul> USA.

With my itinerary and permanent residency in the USA, am I eligible for the 30-day transit visa?

Comment: Do you mind adding your nationality to the question? Its relevant

Comment: Filipino citizen

Answer (score 2):

According to Timatic, the tool used by airlines to check document requirements ([courtesy of Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PH&NV=Philippines&AC=US&AV=United%20States&DC=KR&DV=Korea%2C%20Republic%20of&TC=TW&TV=Taiwan%2C%20China&h=a9e2ef13a940f9689dfdf575aeea48557aa5d1a)), you do not need a visa to enter the Republic of Korea and can stay for up to 30 days. Note that, should you not be staying in Taiwan but transiting, you're limited to 3 days in South Korea.

> **Korea, Republic of (KR**)
>
> **Visa Exemptions:**
>   Nationals of Philippines with a residence permit issued by USA and a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to USA within 30 days. The following itineraries are possible:
>
> - arrive from a third country and departing to USA (e.g. PVG-ICN-USA); or
> - arrive from a third country and depart to another country for a maximum stay of 3 days, before departing to to USA (e.g. PVG-SGN-ICN-USA); or
> - arrive after transiting through a third country for a maximum of 3 days (e.g. PVG-ICN-SGN-USA).
>
> **Chinese Taipei (TW)**
>
> **Visa Exemptions:**
>   Nationals of Philippines with a normal passport for a maximum stay of 14 days.